# Javascript If Statement inside while loop inside a function breaks page

Tags: javascript

Im very,very novice at Javascript but I seem to be breaking my page/function when I add a simple if statement in my function.

Works Perfectly Fine:

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i <= 71) {
  i++;
  var linky = "modal" + i;
    $( "#dialog-form" + i ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 475,
      linky: true,
      buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        linky: false;
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        linky: false;
      }
    });
}
```

Breaks Page:

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i <= 71) {
  i++;
  var linky = "modal" + i;
    $( "#dialog-form" + i ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
     if( i <= 8 ) {
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
     } else {
      height: 400,
      width: 475,
     }
      linky: true,
      buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        linky: false;
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        linky: false;
      }
    });
}
```

Just trying to make the height and width smaller if the id is under 9 but I cant seem to do it without breaking the function.

Comment: That's not valid syntax, check here http://jshint.com

Comment: This is only part of the script, just the part thats breaking but thanks for that tool. Will come in very handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not just putting an `if` in the function, you're putting an `if` in the middle of a javascript object.

This is a valid javascript object:

```
{
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key2: 3
}
```

But you can't add control flow statements (like `if`, `for`, `while`, `switch`) in the middle of this object like that:

```
{
    key1: 1,
    if (true) {     // ERROR
        key2: 2,
    }
    key2: 3
}
```

---

You can achieve what you want by

1. First creating the options object without `height` and `width`.
2. Then do the `if` and add the right values for `height` and `width`.
3. Then call `$( "#dialog-form" + i ).dialog(options)`:

Like this:

```
//STEP 1
var dialogOptions = {
    autoOpen: false,
    linky: true,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            linky: false;
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        linky: false;
    }
};
//STEP 2
if (i <= 8) {
    dialogOptions.height = 300;
    dialogOptions.width = 350;
} else {
    dialogOptions.height = 400;
    dialogOptions.width = 475;
}
//STEP 3
$("#dialog-form" + i).dialog(dialogOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm. Learned something new. Thanks again